# Create an index matrix of combinaison of two variables

Tags: r, combinations

I have this dataframe with four variable

```
data2=data.frame(ths= c("Bu1", "Bu2", "Bu3", "Bu4"), ph=c("na", "na", "na", "na", "a", "a", "a", "a", "u", "u", "u", "u"), nca=c(56, 78, 34, 67, 43, 23, 24, 12, 76, 79, 56, 67), ca=c(29, 7, 51, 18, 13, 33, 32, 44, 4, 1, 23, 13))

> data2
   ths ph nca ca
1  Bu1 na  56 29
2  Bu2 na  78  7
3  Bu3 na  34 51
4  Bu4 na  67 18
5  Bu1  a  43 13
6  Bu2  a  23 33
7  Bu3  a  24 32
8  Bu4  a  12 44
9  Bu1  u  76  4
10 Bu2  u  79  1
11 Bu3  u  56 23
12 Bu4  u  67 13
```

For each ths value (Bu1, Bu2, Bu3, Bu4) I would like to create a matrice based on this dataframe where each line correspond to the row number of ths ph combinaisondata

- Bu1 na vs Bu1 a
- Bu1 na vs Bu1 u
- Bu1 a vs Bu1 u
- Bu2 na vs Bu2 a
- Bu2 na vs Bu2 u
- Bu2 a vs Bu2 u
- Bu3 na vs Bu3 a
- Bu3 na vs Bu3 u
- Bu3 a vs Bu3 u
- Bu4 na vs Bu4 a
- Bu4 na vs Bu4 u
- Bu4 a vs Bu4 u

It would lead to this output

```
> output2
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    5
 [2,]    1    9
 [3,]    5    9
 [4,]    2    6
 [5,]    2   10
 [6,]    6   10
 [7,]    3    7
 [8,]    3   11
 [9,]    7   11
[10,]    4    8
[11,]    4   12
[12,]    8   12
```

In another case where I had this second more simple dataframe and I wanted to create a matrix with all the combinaison of Ths, I used this following code line. The idea is to have something similar for data2. I did not succeed to find a way to do it in this case.

```
data1=data.frame(ths= c("Bu1", "Bu2", "Bu3", "Bu4"), nca=c(56, 78, 34, 67), ca=c(29, 7, 51, 18))

> data1
  ths nca ca
1 Bu1  56 29
2 Bu2  78  7
3 Bu3  34 51
4 Bu4  67 18

outpu1 = t(combn(seq_along(data1$ths),2))

> outpu1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the pairwise row number combinations by group:

```
do.call(rbind, with(data2, tapply(seq_along(ths), ths, \(x) t(combn(x, 2)))))

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    5
 [2,]    1    9
 [3,]    5    9
 [4,]    2    6
 [5,]    2   10
 [6,]    6   10
 [7,]    3    7
 [8,]    3   11
 [9,]    7   11
[10,]    4    8
[11,]    4   12
[12,]    8   12
```

If you prefer `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data2 |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  reframe(x = t(combn(rn, 2)), .by = ths) |>
  pull(x)

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    5
 [2,]    1    9
 [3,]    5    9
 [4,]    2    6
 [5,]    2   10
 [6,]    6   10
 [7,]    3    7
 [8,]    3   11
 [9,]    7   11
[10,]    4    8
[11,]    4   12
[12,]    8   12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
t(do.call(cbind, lapply(split(1:nrow(data2), data2$ths), combn, 2)))
```

or even shorter by using `by`

```
t(do.call(cbind, with(data2, by(seq_along(ths), ths, combn, 2))))
```

which should give

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    5
 [2,]    1    9
 [3,]    5    9
 [4,]    2    6
 [5,]    2   10
 [6,]    6   10
 [7,]    3    7
 [8,]    3   11
 [9,]    7   11
[10,]    4    8
[11,]    4   12
[12,]    8   12
```

Comment: Your first solution is > 2x as fast, though.